# trying to solve $\sqrt{\cos(x)-2\cos(2x)}+\sqrt{2}\cos(2x)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The equation is

$$\sqrt{\cos(x)-2\cos(2x)}+\sqrt{2}\cos(2x)=0$$

The system is

$$
\begin{cases}
\cos(x)-2\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(2x) \\
-\sqrt{2}\cos(2x)\ge 0 \iff \cos(2x)\le 0
\end{cases}
$$

The equation:

$$\cos(x)-2(2\cos^2(x)-1)=2(2\cos^2(x)-1)^2$$
$$\cos(x)-4\cos^2(x)+2=2(4\cos^4(x)-4\cos^2(x)+1)$$
$$\cos(x)-4\cos^2(x)+2=8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+2$$
$$8\cos^4(x)-4\cos^2(x)-\cos(x)=0$$

But what to do next?

If I factor out $\cos(x)$, I get a non-factorizable third-degree polynomial in parentheses

$$\cos(x)(8\cos^3(x)-4\cos(x)-1)=0$$

---

The problem with its solution (upside-down) from the textbook

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$8\cos^3x-4\cos x-1=4\cos x(2\cos^2x-1)$$

$$\implies2(\cos3x+\cos x)=1\iff4\cos x\cos2x=1$$

If $\sin x=0,4\cos x\cos2x\ne1\implies\sin x\ne0$

$$4\cos x\cos2x=1\iff\sin x=2(2\sin x\cos x)\cos2x=2\sin2x\cos2x=\sin4x$$

$$\sin4x=\sin x\implies4x=n\pi+(-1)^nx$$ where $n$ is any integer

Also, $\cos2x\le0\implies2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2\le2x\le2m\pi+\dfrac{3\pi}2$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You can factorise: $$8c^4-4c^2-c=c(2c+1)(4c^2-2c-1)$$

Comment: Thank you! But what method can be used to factorise it? Horner's scheme doesn't seem to work..

Comment: The Factor Theorem, followed by long division

Comment: Thank you! [Found it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyPXqe-KEm4): if $P(\frac{b}{a})=0$ then $ax-b$ is a factor of $P(x)$. P.S. It's strange: I'm trying to divide $8c^3-4c^2-1$ by $(c-(-\frac{1}{2}))$ using Horner's method, and I'm getting a remainder of $-3$.

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake. It's not $-4c^2$, it's $-4c$. Now it works. Yay!